# AppEngine GqlQuery (WHERE NOT)

Tags: database, google-app-engine, gqlquery

I want to find all employees from a company where the telephone number is NOT empty.

Now I have this:

```
db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Employee '
       'WHERE company = :company '
       'AND phone > :nophone', company=company, nophone=None)
```

But this always prints out empty results although there are items with telephone number.

Comment: Does the same query without the filter on 'phone' return any results? Can you provide the model definition and some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Employee  '
  'WHERE company = :company '
  'AND phone != :nophone', company=company, nophone=None)
```

read more about the operators [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax)